# Importing text file : No Columns to parse from file

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to take input from sys.stdin. This is a map reducer program for hadoop. Input file is in txt form. Preview of the data set:

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
166 346 1   886397596
298 474 4   884182806
115 265 2   881171488
253 465 5   891628467
305 451 3   886324817
6   86  3   883603013
62  257 2   879372434
286 1014    5   879781125
200 222 5   876042340
210 40  3   891035994
224 29  3   888104457
303 785 3   879485318
122 387 5   879270459
194 274 2   879539794
291 1042    4   874834944
```

Code that I have been trying -

```
import sys
df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin,error_bad_lines=False)
```

I have also tried with `delimiter = \t, header=False,defining column name`
Nothing seems to work, the error I am getting is this error:

```
[root@sandbox lab]# cat /root/lab/u.data | python /root/lab/mid-1-mapper.py |python /root/lab/mid-1-reducer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/lab/mid-1-reducer.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin,delimiter='\t')
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 388, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 729, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 922, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1389, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 538, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:5896)
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

However, if when I try this directly in python(not in hadoop), it works fine.

I have tried to looked into stackoverflow posts, one of the post suggested try and except. Applying that leaves me with a empty file. 
Can anybody help? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using try and except just lets you continue in spite of errors and handle them. It won't magically fix your errors.

`read_csv` expects `csv` files, which your input is obviously not. A quick look into the documentation:

> delim_whitespace : boolean, default False
>
> Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '    ') will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting sep='+s'. If this option is set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.

This seems like the right argument. Use

```
pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, delim_whitespace=True).
```

Using `delimiter='\t'` should also work, unless the tabs are expanded (replaced by spaces). As we can't really tell, `delim_whitespace` seems to be the better option.

If this doesn't help, just print out your `sys.stdin` to check if you properly pass the text.

Edit:
I just saw that you use

```
cat /root/lab/u.data | python /root/lab/mid-1-mapper.py |python /root/lab/mid-1-reducer.py
```

Is this intended, this way `mid-1-reducer.py` processes the output of `mid-1-mapper.py`. If you want to process the content of the file `u.data` consider reading the file and not `sys.stdin`.

Comment: import sys
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    print df

Comment: Can you print out your `sys.stdin` from within your python scripts (`mid-1-reducer.py` is the one that matters)? You can simply use the `readlines` function or something similar. Does it give the same output as the input you printed in your question?

Comment: I changed the mapper to be this import pandas as pd
import sys
df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin,delim_whitespace=True)
print df
And with the same reducer it seems to work now.

Comment: It was previously just print stdline.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `delim_whitespace` to True, to use whitespaces as the separator.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    print df
```