# Merging csv files in order of date created Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sequence

I am merging 3700 csv files with a total of 10 million rows. The files do not have a sequential naming but the date in which they were created(Descending) is sequential. I use the following code to merge them but do not know how to add pick them in that sequence.

```js
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\User\' #  path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)

    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

> The following are names of files arranged in date modified(oldest to newest) from the os

`V100(1005).csv   V100(1).csv   V100(778).csv   V100(2).csv`

The file names are not sequential because while downloading other files were deleted in between.

Comment: I believe `glob` uses `os`'s default listing, so order is not guaranteed. You probably need to sort `all_files` by manually.

Comment: If you want to sort the files by their name, please provide an example of a file name.

Comment: @EliadL I do not need to sort the files by their name but date created(modified) but I have supplied the names just for good measure

Comment: My bad, I thought the date was incorporated in the file's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need this before the loop (based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python)), which sorts list of files by creation/modification date in Python 3:

```
import os
all_files = sorted(all_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
#all_files = sorted(all_files, key=os.path.getctime) #works too
```

**Test on MacOs**:

- I created 5 files similar to OP:
  [image]
- Using `glob` to read files

```
import glob
all_files = glob.glob('V*.csv')
print(all_files)
#['V100-778.csv', 'V100-778-.csv', 'V100-1005-1.csv', 'V100-1.csv', 'V100-2.csv']
```

- Sorting the files based on modification time:

```
import os
all_files = sorted(all_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
print(all_files)
#['V100-778-.csv', 'V100-1005-1.csv', 'V100-1.csv', 'V100-778.csv', 'V100-2.csv']
```

Comment: Still new to coding. Thank you for your update. The original one did not work since Im using Windows. The updated one worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please checkmark/accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Just FYI, based on my testing, the solution which works for you, worked for MacOS well.

Comment: Thanks for the infor. Just a quick question though, why cant I read moved csv files using pandas? For example, suppose I download a file, V100.csv and read it without moving it with `df = pd.read_csv('V100.csv')` Then move it to a new folder along with the document such that `df = pd.read_csv('V100.csv')` ?

Comment: IIIUC, it is because the path of the files is changed. In that case, you should do `pd.read_csv('Newpath/V100.csv')`. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python) answer for more information about adding a path.

Comment: I understand that one very well but it continues to give me this error: `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

Comment: Could be some formatting issues in the CSV files does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193452/importing-text-file-no-columns-to-parse-from-file/40193853

Comment: Yes Thank you.. `pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, delim_whitespace=True)`  Worked. You truly know your stuff